# Ansible | Kubernetes | Rollout deployment from ansible task

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

How can I run command:
`kubectl rollout restart deployment mydep` from Ansible role? I use k8s module with api key authorization, but this module has not such option. I though about sending requests to api-server, but I have trouble with preparing correct request.
I set verbose (v=10) level of logs for api-server and I tried to retrieve specified request, but it is too unreadable for me.
Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module) or [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/command_module.html#command-module) module in ansible and the option `--kubeconfig` for the kubeconfig file.